# android image to base64 string, and send to php

Tags: php, android, base64

im using this code in the android app, to capture image from camera and send to a javascript file to send a php controller for create file and inset some info to mysql.

the process works fine but the result image is to small and really poor quality

```
if( ACTION_TAKE_PICTURE == requestCode )
     {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap;

        if( null == extras || null == (bitmap=(Bitmap)extras.get("data")) ) return; 
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

        byte [] ba = out.toByteArray();

        String b64img = Base64.encodeToString(out.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        try { out.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}

        wv.loadUrl( String.format("%s%s('%s')", getString(R.string.js_call_prefix), getString(R.string.js_callback_camera), b64img  ));
     }
```

the php code is:

```
    public function executeImagen(sfWebRequest $request) {

    $id = $request->getParameter('id');
    $img = $request->getParameter('img');
    $category = $request->getParameter('category');
    $user = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('id_users');


    try {
        $basepdir = $path = sfConfig::get("sf_upload_dir") . '/photos/';
        $basename = date('Ymd_His');
        $buffer = base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $img));
        $pname = sprintf("%s%s.JPG", $basepdir, $basename);
        $photo = sprintf("%s.JPG", $basename);
        $fd = fopen($pname, "wb"); 

        if ($fd) {
            fwrite($fd, $buffer);
            fflush($fd);
            fclose($fd);
        }
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }

    try {

        $tabla = Doctrine::getTable('StorePhotos');
        $tabla = new StorePhotos();

        $tabla->id_store = $id;
        $tabla->id_category = $category;
        $tabla->id_users = $user;
        $tabla->imagen = $photo;
        $tabla->photo_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $tabla->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        trigger_error("ERROR: ", $e->getMessage());
    }

    return sfView::NONE;
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting and sending the thumbnail. You need to retrieve the full-size image from disk instead. Read [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) by Google.

Comment: Basically you need to send an Intent and pass the uri of the target file in the intent. The camera app will place the picture file at the requested location. Then you just have to read the file back and encode it to base64. Try to encode and upload the file in streaming because image files can be a few megabytes big. If you wan to encode base64 on-the-fly, you can use [Base64OutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64OutputStream.html)

Comment: Thanks, i do this way:      ' ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      
      Base64OutputStream b64img = new Base64OutputStream( out, Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.NO_CLOSE);`, but i get error, seems that image is not found /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/20140422_114840.jpg 'Java.net.MalFormedURLException: protocol not found

Comment: When I suggested to upload the file in streaming, I meant to upload it directly to the network in streaming (using Apache Http client or URLConnection as output stream) and not in RAM, because it can take a lot of RAM. If you use a ByteArrayOutputStream you write everything to memory, and base64 encoding makes the file 33% bigger also.
Your error message probably means that you try to open an URLConnection to an invalid URL.

Comment: ahhhhhh.. the main problem is that i can use this method, cause i send the base64 string to a page that append another fields, for send to a symphony controller... that you see the only way to to this is send a base64 string, could be a compressed image.. - thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are passing the image as a URL parameter of an HTTP GET request? Well, you can only send a few bytes this way, nothing more.
What you need is sending the image as the body of a POST request. That way, you don't even need to encode it in base64 and you can send big files.